# String array combination in R

Tags: arrays, string, r, histogram

I'm starting my studies in R, and even looking for this topic in many forums, I couldn't find a good answer. Maybe I'm not searching using the right terms, or maybe it's not possible to do in R, so please apologize my ignorance.

I would like to find how many times two professionals participates in a given project. Additional to that, I would like to map what is their position when they are found together.

I'm not using a specific notation below. For example, assume I have the following string arrays:

```
Project1: Bob (President), Joe (Vice President), Mary (Participant), Paul (Participant)
Project2: Bob (President), Joe (Vice President), Sue (Participant), Bill (Participant)
Project3: Paul (President), Sue (Vice President), Bob (Participant), Joe (Participant)
Project'n: (...)
```

The output would be:
    Bob (President) & Joe (Vice President) = 2
    Bob (President) & Mary (Participant) = 1
    Bob (President) & Paul (Participant) = 1
    Bob (Participant) & Paul (President) = 1
    Sue (Vice President) & Joe (Participant) = 1

And it goes on and on, and I assume these results could be aggregate in a histogram graph. I have 86 names, participating in 38 different projects, at 3 different possible positions.

Any ideas if it would be possible to do in R? How could it accomplished? Any code templates available or documentation that I could use to get to this answer?

## MY ATTEMPT (START)

```
Groups <- data.frame (Name=c('Paul','Paul','Paul','Bob','Bob','Sue','Bill'),Group=c('P1','P2','P3','P1','P2','P3','P3'),Role=c('President','President','President','Vice President','Vice President','Participant','Participant'))
Table <- table (Groups)
```

When I print 'Table', it shows this output:

```
, , Role = Participant

      Group
Name   P1 P2 P3
  Bill  0  0  1
  Bob   0  0  0
  Paul  0  0  0
  Sue   0  0  1

, , Role = President

      Group
Name   P1 P2 P3
  Bill  0  0  0
  Bob   0  0  0
  Paul  1  1  1
  Sue   0  0  0

, , Role = Vice President

      Group
Name   P1 P2 P3
  Bill  0  0  0
  Bob   1  1  0
  Paul  0  0  0
  Sue   0  0  0
```

Now - for instance - in project "P1" we can see Paul as President and Bob as Vice President. Same happens in project  "P2". In "P3", we have Paul as President plus Sue and Bill both as Participants.

My doubt is now how to count how many occurrences of a given relationship all over the projects. Something like:

```
Paul/President & Bob/Vice = 2 occurrences, 
Paul/President & Sue/Participant = 1 occurrence, 
Paul/President & Bill/Participant = 1 occurrence, etc
```

Basically a 'hist' based on the occurrences of a particular people/role combination.

## MY ATTEMPT (END)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi @ScottRitchie, thanks for your reply. I edited the question with what I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have your `Table`, you can count the occurrence of different types of relationships using `apply` over different sets of axes:

**How many occurrences of different types of participants are there for each project?**

```
> apply(Table, c(2,3), sum)
     Role
Group Participant President Vice President
   P1           0         1              1
   P2           0         1              1
   P3           2         1              0
```

**How many occurrences of Person-Role combinations?**

```
> apply(Table, c(1,3), sum)
      Role
Name   Participant President Vice President
  Bill           1         0              0
  Bob            0         0              2
  Paul           0         3              0
  Sue            1         0              0
```

**Which projects is each person working in?**

```
> apply(Table, c(1,2), sum)
      Group
Name   P1 P2 P3
  Bill  0  0  1
  Bob   1  1  0
  Paul  1  1  1
  Sue   0  0  1
```

**How many projects is each person working on?**

```
> apply(Table, 1, sum)
Bill  Bob Paul  Sue 
   1    2    3    1
```

**How many people are involved in each project?**

```
> apply(Table, 2, sum)
P1 P2 P3 
 2  2  3
```

**How many people belong to each role?**

```
> apply(Table, 3, sum)
   Participant      President Vice President 
             2              3              2
```

Comment: Thanks @ScottRitchie. It helped a lot for a couple of topics I need to evaluate for this dataset. I did something here that also helps me in such evaluations. As in the comments box the # of characters is limited, I'll answer my own question with what I did a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @ScottRitchie for your tips. After some additional readings and tests, I came out with the following:

A csv file was imported with columns containing the name, project and role. I also added another column at the end, like a counter (with a constant value of 1 from end to end).

I did:

```
Groupings <-read.csv("~/Documents/TCC_BIGDATA/Test.csv", sep=";")
Groupings$Counter <- as.integer(Groupings$Counter)
print(Groupings)

       Project       Name     Role            Counter
1       P1           Paul     President       1
2       P1           Bob      Vice President  1
3       P1           Sue      Participant     1
4       P1           Bill     Participant     1
5       P2           Paul     Vice President  1
6       P2           Bob      Participant     1
7       P2           Bill     President       1
8       P3           Bob      President       1
9       P3           Bill     Vice President  1
10      P3           Sue      Participant     1
```

How many times a name shows in the list?

```
aggregate(Counter ~ Name, data = Groupings, sum)

  Name Counter
1 Bill       3
2  Bob       3
3 Paul       2
4  Sue       2
```

How many times a Name+Role combination shows in the list?

```
aggregate(Counter ~ Name + Role, data = Groupings, sum)

  Name           Role Counter
1 Bill    Participant       1
2  Bob    Participant       1
3  Sue    Participant       2
4 Bill      President       1
5  Bob      President       1
6 Paul      President       1
7 Bill Vice President       1
8  Bob Vice President       1
9 Paul Vice President       1
```

And other exercises and combinations can be made. At the end, it is just another way to achieve the same you (@ScottRitchie) built to answer my question. I thought it would be a good idea to share so others could apply.